# Navigation after IPC in Liferay

Tags: jsf, liferay, ipc, liferay-6, portlet

we want to navigate in Liferay to an other portlet after receiving a IPC-Event.
So we send the event from one portlet, implemented an second Portlet extends from MVCPortlet, and receive the event with some information!
So we want to navigate in Liferay to the second portlet.

The methode were we receive the event is this

```
@ProcessEvent(qname = "{http://liferay.com}empinfo")
public void handleProcessempinfoEvent(final javax.portlet.EventRequest request, final javax.portlet.EventResponse response) throws javax.portlet.PortletException, java.io.IOException
```

Also we override the methods from com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet but no one was called after sending the event.

Is there any way to navigate inside liferay (6.1.2)?

Thx Tim

Answer (score 0):

Is the event handled at all? What do you mean with "navigate to the second portlet"?. Events - by default - only get distributed to the portlets that appear on the same page. If you want to receive an event on a portlet that exists on a different page, you'll have to explicitly configure Liferay to distribute events to all pages in the same site. Note that this might dig into your performance. Also - once you navigate to another page - by default the portlet's state on that page is being reset.

Check the following (and related) portal.properties:

```
#
# Set this property to specify how events are distributed. If the value is
# "layout-set", then events will be distributed to all portlets contained in
# a layout set. If the value is "layout", then events will be distributed to
# all portlets that are present in a layout.
#
portlet.event.distribution=layout

#
# Set this property to specify how public render parameters are distributed.
# If the value is "layout-set", then public render parameters will be
# distributed to all portlets contained in a layout set. This will only work
# correctly if the property "layout.default.p_l_reset" is set to false. If
# the value is "layout", then public render parameters will be distributed
# to all portlets that are present in a layout.
#
portlet.public.render.parameter.distribution=layout

#
# Set the default value for the "p_l_reset" parameter. If set to true,
# render parameters are cleared when different pages are hit. This is not
# the behavior promoted by the portlet specification, but is the one that
# most end users seem to prefer.
#
layout.default.p_l_reset=true
```

If you intend to navigate to a different page, you'll also have to note that this is not covered by the portlet API. Thus you'll have to identify how to find the relevant page, its URL and how to redirect. It's probably easier to have some more logic in the action-handling portlet and do the redirect there: At least you'll only handle one action. Potentially there might be several Events handled per Action - thus it's undefined which potential redirect will be triggered if they conflict. I'd see a real redirect (any way) as rather unexpected behavior if it comes from an EventHandler, but somewhat understandable from an ActionHandler.